# Error when using ''ward'' method with pvclust R package

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering, pvclust

I am having some troubles regarding a cluster analysis that I am trying to do with the *pvclust* package.

Specifically, I have a data matrix composed by species (rows) and sampling stations (columns). I want to perform a CA in order to group my sampling stations according to my species abundance (which I have previously log(x+1) transformed).

Once having prepared adequately my matrix,I've tried to run a CA according to the pvclust package, using Ward's clustering method and Bray-Curtis as distance index. However, every time I get the following error message:

''Error in hclust(distance, method = method.hclust) : 
  invalid clustering method''

I then tried to perform the same analysis using another cluster method, and I had no problem. I also tried to perform the same analysis using the hclust function from the *vegan* package, and I had no problem at all, too. The analysis run without any problems.

To better understand my problem, I'll display part of my matrix and the
script that I used to perfrom the analysis:

```
          P1        P2         P3         P4         P5       P6
1  10.8750000 3.2888889  2.0769231  1.4166667  3.2395833 5.333333
3   0.3645833 0.3027778  0.3212038  0.7671958  0.4993676 0.000000
4   0.0000000 0.0000000  2.3500000  0.0000000  0.0000000 0.264000
5   0.0000000 0.7333333  0.2692308  0.0000000  0.2343750 0.000000
6   0.0000000 0.9277778  0.0000000  0.2936508  0.7291667 0.000000
7   0.4166667 6.3500000  1.0925463  0.5476190  0.1885169 0.000000
8   1.6250000 0.0000000  0.0000000  0.0000000  5.2187500 0.000000
9   0.0000000 0.8111111  0.0000000  0.0000000  0.0000000 0.000000
10  2.6770833 0.6666667  2.3304890  4.5906085  2.9652778 0.000000
15  1.8020833 0.9666667  1.4807137  3.3878968  0.1666667 0.000000
16 17.8750000 4.9555556  1.4615385  6.5000000  7.8593750 7.666667
19  4.5312500 1.0555556  3.5766941  6.7248677  2.3196181 0.000000
20  0.0000000 0.6777778  0.5384615  0.0000000  0.0000000 0.000000
21  0.0000000 0.9777778  0.0000000  0.2500000  0.0000000 0.000000
24  1.2500000 3.0583333  0.1923077  0.0000000  4.9583333 0.000000
25  0.0000000 0.0000000  2.5699634  0.0000000  0.0000000 0.000000
26  6.6666667 2.2333333 24.8730020 55.9980159 17.6239583 0.000000
```

Where P1-P6 are my sampling stations, and the leftmost row numbers are my different species. I'll denote this example matrix just as ''platforms''.

Afterwards, I've used the following code lines:

```
dist <- function(x, ...){
  vegdist(x, ...)
}

result<-pvclust(platforms,method.dist = "bray",method.hclust = "ward")
```

It is noteworthy that I run the three first codelines, since the bray-curtis index isn't originally available in the pvclust package. Thus, running these codelines allowed me to specify the bray-curtis index in the pvclust function

Does anyone know why it doesn't work with the pvclust package?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Kind regards,

Marie

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example, with code and sample data. Right now, it's hard to diagnose - it could be as simple as needing to type `ward.D` or `ward.D2` when using `stats::hclust`, where `pvclust::pvclust` takes `ward`.

Comment: Hi Michael,

I've already updated my post in order to provide a practical example of my issue.

Comment: Beware that Ward's method is based on *squared Euclidean*. So while you may get back a result with other distances, it may no longer be backed by the original theory of Ward.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two related issues:

1. When calling `method.hclust` you need to pass *hclust* compatible methods. In theory `pvclust` checks for `ward` and converts to `ward.D`, but you probably want to pass the (correct) names of either `ward.D` or `ward.D2`.
2. You cannot over-write `dist` in that fashion. However, you *can* pass a custom function to `pvclust`.

For instance, this should work:

```
library(vegan)
library(pvclust)

sample.data <- "P1  P2  P3  P4  P5  P6
10.8750000  3.2888889   2.0769231   1.4166667   3.2395833   5.3333330
0.3645833   0.3027778   0.3212038   0.7671958   0.4993676   0.0000000
0.0000000   0.0000000   2.3500000   0.0000000   0.0000000   0.2640000
0.0000000   0.7333333   0.2692308   0.0000000   0.2343750   0.0000000
0.0000000   0.9277778   0.0000000   0.2936508   0.7291667   0.0000000
0.4166667   6.3500000   1.0925463   0.5476190   0.1885169   0.0000000
1.6250000   0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000   5.2187500   0.0000000
0.0000000   0.8111111   0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000
2.6770833   0.6666667   2.3304890   4.5906085   2.9652778   0.0000000
1.8020833   0.9666667   1.4807137   3.3878968   0.1666667   0.0000000
17.8750000  4.9555556   1.4615385   6.5000000   7.8593750   7.6666670
4.5312500   1.0555556   3.5766941   6.7248677   2.3196181   0.0000000
0.0000000   0.6777778   0.5384615   0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000
0.0000000   0.9777778   0.0000000   0.2500000   0.0000000   0.0000000
1.2500000   3.0583333   0.1923077   0.0000000   4.9583333   0.0000000
0.0000000   0.0000000   2.5699634   0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000
6.6666667   2.2333333   24.8730020  55.9980159  17.6239583  0.0000000"

platforms <- read.table(text = sample.data, header = TRUE)

result <- pvclust(platforms, 
                  method.dist = function(x){
                    vegdist(x, "bray")
                  },
                  method.hclust = "ward.D")
```

Comment: Hi Michael,

Thank you for your fast reply.
Unfortunately, I still get an error message after running your code lines.
This time, after running your codelines, I get the following message:

_Error in as.character(x) : 
  cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'_

Any idea what's happening now?

Comment: I just added sample data - does it work with what I provided? I suspect there might be something off with `platforms`.

Comment: It didn't work, and the same error message appeared again.
I've double checked my data matrix (which is actually a data frame), and everything seems normal.

Just to see what I have, here are the first line of my data matrix structure:

'data.frame': 17 obs. of  13 variables:
 $ P1 : num  10.875 0.365 0 0 0 ...
 $ P2 : num  3.289 0.303 0 0.733 0.928 ...
 $ P3 : num  2.077 0.321 0 0.269 0 ...
 $ P4 : num  1.417 0.767 0 0 0.294 ...

Comment: @Marie-ChristineRufener try it now

Comment: @rawr It is still appearing the same error message as before, i.e., _Error in as.character(x) : cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'_

Comment: @Marie-ChristineRufener michael's example works perfectly fine for me, try a clean r session or you'r doing something differently than us

Comment: @rawr I don't know what's happening, but running these code lines on my computer doesn't work. However, when I run them in a friend's computer, it works perfectly! I have already cleaned my R session and shut down my computer, but even after this it still didn't work. Do you know what may happening in this case?

Comment: Can you upgrade to the latest version of R? You may be using an older (out of date) version of R, and therefore also of the packages.

Comment: @MichaelGriffiths I think that the main problem was reall my R version! I updated it and afterwards all the code lines here discussed worked without any problem.
Thank you very much for your help