# Computing p-values when using pvclust with Bray-Curtis similarity

Tags: r, hierarchical-clustering, bootstrapping, vegan, pvclust

Using species abundance data recorded for multiple samples, I want to create a dendrogram where branches represent the similarity of samples. The distance measure should be Bray-Curtis-similarity. For each node, I want to obtain p-values indicating stability by bootstrapping. The function `pvclust()` from the R package `pvclust` seems to be suitable for this problem. Unfortunately, Bray-Curtis-similarity is not natively implemented as a distance measure in `pvclust`. However, it is possible to pass a function which returns a dist object to the `method.dist` argument of `pvclust`. `vegdist` from the `vegan` package seems suitable.

Following the approach from an answer, I found here: [Error when using ''ward'' method with pvclust R package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39900491/error-when-using-ward-method-with-pvclust-r-package), my current approach is the following (using the dune dataset from the package `vegan`):

```r
# load libraries
library(vegan)
library(pvclust)

# load example data
data(dune)

# run pvclust
pv_result <- pvclust(dune,
                     method.hclust = "ward.D",
                     method.dist = function(x){vegan::vegdist(x, "bray")},
                     n = 1000,
                     parallel = TRUE)

# plot result
plot(pv_result)
```

This returns the following dendrogram:

[image]

The calculation of p-values does not seem to work, since they are 0 for all nodes. I am looking for a way to calculate the p-values. Also approaches using alternatives to `pvclust` are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function `pvclust` seems to transpose input data and calculate the clustering for columns (variables) instead of rows (observations). This means that you need to transpose input in your `method.dist` function as well. Moreover, if you want to have clustering for rows, you must undo the transpose by transposing your input. You should modify your call as:

```r
library(pvclust)
library(vegan)
data(dune)
pvclust(t(dune), # to cluster rows - omit t() to cluster columns
   method.dist = function(x) vegan::vegdist(t(x), "bray"), 
   n = 1000) # and other arguments you need
```

NB, you need `t(x)` in the `vegdist` call in all cases.

Comment: This solution works perfectly fine. Many thanks for figuring out that transposing in the function is necessary, Jari!

Comment: `pvclust` primarily uses correlation and related measures. These operate on columns (variables). If you want to provide your alternative measure using functions that operate on rows, you need to transpose for consistency.